# Fullscreen with pyqt4?

Tags: python, pyqt, fullscreen

I'm new to pyqt and I've been looking for some docs about pyqt and fullscreen mode. but I couldn't find nothing. So here is my question:

is there any way to run a PyQT 4 application on fullscreen?

Comment: It may depend upon your window manager; in `i3`, for example, the default `Mod1+f` will toggle fullscreen mode for a client window.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

use **showFullScreen()** on your widget.

Comment: awesome, thanks!! I thought it would be more complicated, I expected it to be at least 3 lines... :D

Comment: @Macumbaomuerte `self.showNormal()` or `self.showMaximized()`.