# Getting started with fullscreen Python desktop GUIs

Tags: python, graphical-programming

There seems to be multiple GUI libraries for Python. I wish to develop a desktop application (e.g. for Windows), with a completely custom design - basically, using sprites or mathematical objects. In the case of effects, one requirement is a neon glow for buttons.

Which library/libraries are suitable for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **full screen** use `showFullScreen()` on your widget.

You can use **PyQT** with **QSS** for GUI.

> QSS : Its a variant of CSS with most of the properties intersecting
>   with CSS styles and specially designed to work and design the Qt guis
>   and widgets. But instead of HTML tags we use the Widgets class name
>   for styling them, like :- QWidget, QLineEdit, QLabel, QPushButton etc.
>   etc.

e.g.:

```
QWidget {
   background-color: #222222;
}

QLineEdit {
   background-color: aliceblue;
   color: #618b38;
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: bold;
}

QLabel {
   background-color: #222222;
   color: #618b38;
}

QPushButton {
   background-color: #8b0000;
   color: #ffffff;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border-style: none;
   height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Great, then I could use fullscreen! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541771/fullscreen-with-pyqt4

Comment: Is it possible to create a neon glow effect in PyQT?

Comment: QSS is a variant of CSS, try it, check this: https://codepen.io/FelixRilling/pen/qzfoc